# How to download a file from a system folder when a link is clicked?

Tags: files, media

I have a file("abc.csv") that is stored in the local system (for example: /var/a). I need to download the file when I hit a link in a Drupal site.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal comes with options to define where the website media/files are stored. You can find it under Configuration > Media > File system (`/admin/config/media/file-system`).

You can assign a folder on the local system/server that serves as a Public files folder, and another folder that serves as a Private files folder.

Public files can be accessed by anonymous users (if they know the link), but Private files can't be downloaded even if you know the link to them if you don't have the appropriate user role that has access to the file (through Drupal Permissions, and of course if your server setup is properly secured).

Both options are tightly connected with the server permissions configuration. It's very important to configure your Drupal installation with secure server user folders and files ownership and permissions. If you have a "leaky" configuration your website can be hacked easily. Read more about folders and files permissions: [Securing file permissions and ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924).

That is why it isn't a good idea to allow your Drupal website to link to just any file on the server/local system, and instead Drupal gives you one location to store all of the files you might need to display/link on your website.

It is possible to configure your Drupal installation to use the `/var/a` folder to store the Public files, but it requires expert server administration knowledge to make it work and make it secure.

Usually the Public files folder is held in the location:  `/sites/default/files` (this is relative to the Drupal root installation folder, it is inside the Drupal folder).

If you upload a file to a Drupal Field and you don't define any custom options, or if you directly upload your files to that location you can link to the file with this path:

`/sites/default/files/abc.csv`

The full link would be:

`<a href="/sites/default/files/abc.csv">Download my File</a>`

Drupal keeps a record of files uploaded through Files API, and you can use Views to create lists of files, that display file names, links to download, and even other file information. That is a very handy way to automatically create links to files, if you have a lot of them.

Comment: i have to download the file when we give the "url" ? is it possible to create a custom module for getting the file and download it .

Comment: The file isn't downloaded when you create the link. It is only when you click on the link on Drupal website that the file is downloaded. Or do you mean something different? Do you want to import the files from a local folder into Drupal? There are modules that can do that. You'll probably have to copy the files from your local folder into Drupal, and then use the Import interface so that Drupal can download and store those files in its files folder automatically.

Comment: what i mean that there is a URL when ever we search the URL it get the file from our local folder and download. That i want it.

Comment: What do you mean "search the URL"? The file will always be in the same location, unless you move it or delete it.

Comment: consider there is a file in "/var/a/exp.csv" location when i search a url "http://localhost/transgenic/download" i have to download the file "exp.csv" .That means when search happen it goes to the specified location and get the file from there then it download to specified destination folder.

Comment: Does this mean you just want an alias for the file path so the user doesn't know where on the server the file is located?

Comment: we already create a crud function for creating the file in every day ( night 10- 12 pm this crud will run and create a file in a location and delete the previous created file ).so when the user search url then "Download the file to destination location" from  the file exist in the stored  location

Comment: It's still not clear where the destination location is. Do you want to store that file in Drupal? Please ask a new question with _all_ the relevant information.